# How to create a new array from another array based on the number of a specific character like "o" in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need an array that every item in it have at max one "o" character

array = ["book", "saloon", "dog", "solomon", "cow", "cat", "tire", "window"]

// the array that I need:

newArray = ["dog", "cow", "cat", "tire", "window"]

could anyone help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? 
SO is there to learn and not to get results posted, therefor I am interested in your ideas of finding a solution.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I dont have any idea what should I do @DavidThomas

Comment: Are you sure that example is correct? I can't understand the logic behind the expected array

Comment: @RomanMahotski I need every words that have at max one "O"

Comment: if there are 2 or more "O" I should remove it from the list

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to count the number of "o" occurrences in the string:

```
(s.match(/o/gi) || []).length
```

- `g` Global search
- `i` Assuming you want Case-insensitive search

Then you can [Array#filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Code:

```js
const array = ["book", "saloon", "dog", "solomon", "cow", "cat", "tire", "window"]

const newArray = array.filter(s => (s.match(/o/gi) || []).length <= 1)

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: @MoeenHeydari good to help